# Generate auto sequence in SQL server as AB001...AB999

Tags: sql-server

I want to generate SQL sequence for the table(table name - Employee).

column(Emp_Title) as

> AB001.....AB999 once the value reaches to AB999

it should automatically start with **AC001...AC999** and from here again start with **AD001......AD999**. The process will go upto **ZZ001......ZZ999**.

This sequence I will be using to insert a new employee record in my employee table.

Example As -

```
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[SequenceCounter], 'EmpName', 'EmpDesignation', 'EmpSalary')
```

Comment: Tag properly!  If this is `SQL Server`, why is the tag `MySQL`?  They're two completely different products.

Comment: Hi,this is corrected. I am using SQL server 2012.

Comment: In other words, the question is how to convert a *number* to an  alphanumeric string. One way would be to divide by 1000, keep the remainder as the last 3 digits and use map the *quotient* to text. The set-based way to do that would be to create a lookup table that maps 0 to AA, 1 to AB and so on, up to ZZ

Comment: As per the recent search, I just got a function to obtain the sequence on the site https://www.sqlteam.com/articles/custom-auto-generated-sequences-with-sql-server. But I still need help because this function is taking a parameter whereas in my requirement I don't have to supply any parameter. The sequence should increase the alphanumeric string automatically once it is called.

Comment: The sequence should work as an identity column for the table. Likewise identity increases the sequence should increase this alphanumeric format (AB001....AB999).

Comment: Why do you have a requirement not to use a parameter?   Is this for a school assignment?   The article in the link you referenced is pretty exhaustive.   If none of the solutions in that article work for you, then what you want simply isn't possible.   There are no better ways to do what you want.

Comment: The requirement is to save new employee record into the database where employee title should be in this format. On hitting the sequence the new unique emp_Title should get assigned to the respective employee, hence parameter is not required. I am developing a C# windows form application for one of my friend's MSME.

Comment: If not by using sequence, is there any other way we can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place an Identity column on this table and then a computed column to transform the identity value into the format you want.  Something like the following should work:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
   [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [EmpName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
   [EmpDesignation] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
   [EmpSalary] [Money] NOT NULL,
   [Emp_Title]  AS ((CHAR((65)+([ID]/(1000))/(26))+CHAR((65)+([ID]/(1000))%(26)))+FORMAT((([ID]-1)%(1000)+1),'000'))       
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Or you could create a view that would manipulate your ID field to display only in the format for which you are looking.

In either case you'd need to put a constraint in place on the ID to keep it under the max value that would generate the ZZ999 ID, if my calcs are correct that would be 675999.

Comment: Hi, this is working fine as per the requirement. Thanks a lot for giving me the solution. :)

Comment: Hi Chad, good day! I need your help, to know if I have to run the same SQL query in SQL 2012 Express what would be the statement? As the following statement is giving me the error in SQL 2012 Express : Statement : FORMAT((([ID]-1)%(1000)+1),'000'))    Error : format' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: You can get similar results to:
    FORMAT((([ID]-1)%(1000)+1),'000'))

If you convert it to:
    Right('000'+CAST((([ID]-1)%(1000)+1) AS Int), 3)

Albeit, the performance will probably not be as good.

Comment: I tried this but is giving me error :- Incorrect syntax near ' , '                            My full statement is     [EmpCode]  AS ((char((65)+([EmpID]/(1000))/(26))+char((65)+([EmpID]/(1000))%(26)))+Right('000'+CAST((([EmpID]-1)%(1000)+1) AS varchar(10)), 3)

Comment: Looks like you missed one closing parenthesis at the very end.

Comment: This works now. Thanks a bunch for helping me again on this subject. :D